# Diffeomorphism between boundaries

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ and $N$ be two smooth manifolds homeomorphic to $S^n$ such that $N=\partial B$, for some (n+1)-smooth manifold $B$.

Suppose that there is a diffeomorphism $f:M \rightarrow N$. Can I find a manifold $C$ such that $M= \partial C$ and $C$ is diffeomorphic to $B$? In other words, I want to "pullback" $B$ using $f$ (or an extension) to obtain such a manifold $C$.

(This is not true in the case that $f$ is a homeomorphism)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see what's the problem here. If $M$ is already diffeomorphic to $N$, then you can basically say $M = \partial B$. The fact that they're not literally equal as sets is merely incidental. As far as differential topology cares, $M$ and $N$ are the same thing (unless you have some additional structure you haven't mentioned).

Comment: "The fact that they're not literally equal as sets is merely incidental."

So, can you write explicitly $C$ ? I can see that $f(M) = \partial B$, but without an extension from $N$ to $B$, I can't see how to write $C$

Comment: Also, if $M=\partial B$, $N= \partial C$ are smooth manifolds and $f:M \rightarrow N$ is a homeomorphism, so $C$ and $B$ may not be homeomorphic (!!!): For example, take $M=S^7$ and $N$ an exotic sphere and $B=D^8$. Then, you have that $dim H^4(C) \neq 0$ which implies that $C$ and $B$ are not homeomorphic. So, the argument $M \cong N$ and $N= \partial B$ implies $C \cong B$ is really not clear to me

Comment: The fact that a manifold can be the boundary of two different manifolds has little to do with what I said (and there are such examples much simpler than the one you quoted, e.g. just remove a small disk from two different closed surfaces)

Comment: Your argument was: $M \cong N$ and $N=\partial B$ implies $M=\partial C$ with $C \cong B$. I gave you an example (in the homeomorphic case) where this argument is invalid

Comment: The point of my example was: If $N$ is an exotic sphere (in this case, the total space of a sphere bundle), there is no manifold $B$ homeomorphic to the 8-disk such that $N= \partial B$.

Comment: There is a manifold $B$ homeomorphic to the $8$-disk such that $N$ is homeomorphic to $\partial B$. That's all you could ask for. Or, if you insist on how manifolds are encoded as sets, you could say $N = \partial B$, with the caveat that the smooth structure on $N$ is not the one induced by $B$. This is what is reasonable to expect, since you only have a homeomorphism and so no reason to want smooth structures preserved.

Comment: "with the caveat that the smooth structure on $N$ is not the one induced by $B$." which makes $B$ irrelevant in this context. 

(Behind this, the ideia was to show that a certain number, calculated using some characteristic classes (which are invariants under homeomorphisms) of the boundary, is an invariant for diffeomorphisms, but not homeomorphisms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; you just take $B$ and "replace" each point of $N$ with the corresponding point of $M$.  There is nothing deep here at all; this is just the usual argument that isomorphic structures are interchangeable.

Explicitly, let us first assume that the set $B$ is disjoint from $M$.  In that case, define the set $C$ to be $(B\setminus N)\cup M$, and define $g:C\to B$ by $g(c)=c$ if $c\in B\setminus N$ and $g(c)=f(c)$ if $c\in M$.  There is a unique way to make $C$ a smooth manifold with boundary such that $g$ is a diffeomorphism (namely, take the topology to consist of all sets $g^{-1}(U)$ for $U\subseteq B$ open, and define the charts on $C$ to be the composition of $g$ with charts on $B$).  Since $g$ is a diffeomorphism, it must restrict to a diffeomorphism $\partial C\to \partial B$.  Since $\partial B=N$ and $g^{-1}(N)=M$, we have $\partial C=M$ as a set.  Moreover, the restriction of $g$ to $M$ is just the map $f$, which we assumed was a diffeomorphism for the given smooth manifold structure on $M$.  So $f$ is a diffeomorphism $M\to N$ both for the given smooth manifold structure on $M$ and for the smooth manifold structure obtained by considering $M$ as the boundary of $C$.  Thus these two smooth manifold structures on $M$ are the same (the identity map is a diffeomorphism between them).  That is $\partial C$ is $M$ with its original smooth manifold structure.

In case $B$ is not disjoint from $M$, you just have to make it disjoint first.  Take $B'$ to be some set with a bijection $h:B\to B'$ such that $B'\cap M=\emptyset$.  Make $B'$ a smooth manifold in the unique way such that $h$ is a diffeomorphism.  Let $N'=\partial B'$ and let $f':M\to N'$ be the composition $h|_N\circ f$, which is a diffeomorphism since $h|_N$ and $f$ are.  We can now apply the previous paragraph with $(B',f',N')$ in place of $(B,f,N)$.

Comment: Nice and very clear! Thank you.